# an 500 error while calling codeigniter functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project developed with code igniter first I've uploaded it in a folder and I call it from this are exemple.com/code and after I've moved it in the head and I call it exemple.com but in this case all my functions don't work it showed me a 500 internal server error 
Any ideas 
Thanks

Comment: Look into the web server’s error log file.

Comment: i don't have access !

Comment: then start stuffing debug statements all over the place so you can narrow down what part of the code is causing it to barf.

Comment: all the code is correct and it was working until i've moved the folder into the head of the www